# WPF Focus behavior issue

Tags: wpf

I have two views for e.g  'A'.Xaml and 'B'.Xaml  . In A.Xaml I have a textbox and B.Xaml I Have a Button  , on click of Button present in the 'B' View ,the focus should be set on the control (textBox) present in 'A'.Xaml(View). How to achieve this .I tried many ways uisng Focus behaviour,Focuselement,Focusable etc ,I see the main issue is How to set focus on control present in different view ,when action is performed in different view?Please reply .Thanks in advance
Krishna

Answer (score 1):

You need to somehow have a reference to the `A` view from within your `B` view. Then you simply use an event on the `Button` in `B`

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    windowA.txtSomeTextBox.Focus();
}
```

Something similar to that. I don't actually know what you named your controls, so those parts are probably wrong (since I guessed them).

---

Note, that this is just one way of doing it. There are many other ways of doing it, for exmaple... if you use the Prism framework you can use an `EventAggregator` to publish an event between two views that are unrelated, or from a viewmodel that binds the `Button` to a `Command` which publishes the event, and the subscriber (the view) captures that event and does what it needs to do. Etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            txtSomeTextBox.Focus();
        });
```

You may also want to try `Application.Current.MainWindow` to gain access into `A.xaml`.